# How do I encrypt this password with MD5 using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, authentication, md5

The code below is from a login script, written in PHP. The database that it checks passwords against encrypts the passwords using MD5 however when the login script checks against the database for a password, it is checking the raw password without encryption. I am familiar with the md5() function but how would I incorporate that into the following:

```
<?php
session_start();

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if ($username && $password) {
    $connect = mysql_connect("host", "user", "password") or die("Couldn't connect");
    mysql_select_db("dbname") or die("Couldn't find the database");

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

    if ($numrows != 0) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            $dbusername = $row['username'];
            $dbpassword = $row['password'];
        }

        if ($username == $dbusername && $password == $dbpassword) {
            echo "You're in! Click <a href='../member.php'>here</a> to enter the member page.";
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        }else{
            echo "Incorrect password";
        }
    }else{
        die("That username does not exist.");
    }
}else{
    die("Please enter a valid username and password.");
}
?>
```

Comment: Changing `$password == $dbpassword` to `md5($password) == $dbpassword` should work.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to famous SQL Injection.

Comment: Still working on the mysql_escape_real_string() stuff as well

Comment: MD5 is [nowhere near good enough](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords?lq=1) for this purpose.

Comment: Before touching mysql_escape_real_string, use mysli or PDO instead with prepared statements. No need to actually continue to learn mysql_* nowadays.

Answer (score 5):

You should be checking and querying the database for a match, not bringing the results down and checking them locally. With that said:

```
$password = md5($_POST['password']);
```

Then also change:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'
```

But I'd also have a look at using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead of placing the values directly in a SQL query. At the very least you should be using [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to avoid injection attacks.

Comment: I would also recommend not to use MD5 as it gives you practically no security. bcrypt or PBKDF2

Comment: @ExplosionPills Right, or use salt. But better is something stronger with salt.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $salt=sha1($postpassword);
    $arr= strlen($postpassword);
    $count=ceil($arr/2);
    $stringarr=str_split($postpassword,$count);
    $password1=hash("sha512", $stringarr['0']); 

    $password2=$salt . ( hash( 'whirlpool', $salt . $stringarr['1'] ) );
    return $password1.$password2;
```

Comment: <?php 
class password {
  
 
  
 // get a new hash for a password

 public function stringbreak ($postpassword)
 {
  $salt=sha1($postpassword);
  $arr= strlen($postpassword);
  $count=ceil($arr/2);
  $stringarr=str_split($postpassword,$count);
  $password1=hash("sha512", $stringarr['0']); 
  
  $password2=$salt . ( hash( 'whirlpool', $salt . $stringarr['1'] ) );
  return $password1.$password2;
 } 

 

 
 
}

?>