# UPDATE or DELETE in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have gone through this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19575528/update-user-list-in-group-update-or-delete-insert)
I have a Database that has id,password,date of birth.

```
id|name|password|dob
1 |avi |vx1     |2013-1-1
```

I have a few questions lets say a user wishes to change his/her password then what is the correct way to go should I use `UPDATE user SET password='pusheen' WHERE id=1` or Should I delete the value first and then Insert the value in the column.

(I understand password should be inserted in database in encrypted form but I`m newbie learning so saving it as plain text.)

The link above suggests not to use update is the  **case** in above link similar to mine?

The same goes for any other field lets say I wish to have name field as blank/null.

whats the command to delete a field say name where id=1 and insert again? each time I try to delete I end up deleting the whole row.

is use of `UPDATE user SET name=NULL WHERE id=1` not the correct way?

Comment: That post relates to users and groups - you can just use an update statement. Also, newbie or not, you really must encrypt passwords..

Comment: You should update user info for existing users and insert for new user.

Comment: Update the row. Also, newbies especially should not save passwords as plain text.

Comment: UPDATE is the only way to change data already present right?Is it the same as REPLACE

Comment: Just update =] So delete for removing and update for updating ;) the link is not different scenerio then the one you have.

Comment: @1994 REPLACE != UPDATE

Comment: @stuartd I agree but when it come to encrypting a post here at SO says that use of sha1 md5 does not give much protection but instead another encryption technique must be used

Comment: @1994 crypt() and then md5().

Comment: what does REPLACE do that different from UPDATE?

Comment: Update is the better way and that actually also clears your intent.
Give each user a unique id on insertion in DB and enforce this by making the field PRIMARY or UNIQUE. You can use this id to update the DB.
Also, as mentioned encrypt the password. Learning about salting and encrypting is not hard and will go along a long way for you as a dev.

Comment: No, not `crypt` and then `md5`, that's nonsense. Use a [strong password hashing algorithm](http://php.net/password).

Comment: @erosenin can you provide any helpful links? is use of sha1 not good practice?

Comment: sha1 is *way* too fast to be good enough, it's rather easy to regenerate a SHA1 checksum.

Comment: @user689 A post here a t SO says that md5 and sha1 are not the best hashing algorithms as for crypt well I don`t know much can you elaborate

Comment: @1994 sha1 has less randomness. Just read about hashing algorithms. There are better SHA algorithms out there like SHA512. About the link, have a look at what Marcel Korpel linked. It looks like a good place to start.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel my way is to use [crypt](http://php.net/crypt) with a specific salt and then md5 the password so they all have the same length(plus more protection), what is wrong with it?

Comment: @user689 You end up with an MD5sum after all, that's wrong with it. Don't try to reinvent a cryptographic algorithm if you're not an encryption expert (neither am I), but use the best possible algorithms in the field, preferably [`password_hash`](http://php.net/password_hash) with the default hashing options (use the strongest available hashing algorithm, if stronger hashing algorithms are implemented, the function will use that instead of the current default) and let the function generate a random salt. That's simply the best your can go nowadays.

Comment: @1994 What are you actually trying to do? I don't understand what your problem is. Do you want to delete a user from your database? Do you want to update their password?

Comment: @Marcel Korpel I wanna know if simply using UPDATE or delete then insert which among the 2 should be used and I have found the answer here in comments

Answer (score 3):

You can delete the record simply by using

```
delete from user where id = 1
```

but if you are going to update the user password,then you don't need to delete and insert as new one.. you can simply use the update statement like

```
UPDATE user SET password='pusheen' WHERE id=1
```

If you want to insert new user, then only goes to insert statement like

```
  insert into user(id,name,password,dob) values
  (2,'name','password','11/11/1985')
```

Aside: You should not store passwords as plain text ever. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12666236/822711) shows the simplest method that you will not have a problem using. It's better than nothing.

Comment: Again, don't store passwords in plain text, you should not encourage that bad practice.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel friend, i'm just give explanation about the type of query needed in his situation. not going to the encrypted password field.i'm not encourage this practise.

Comment: Downvoter please comment..? This answer is correct. If this was downvoted because of the plain text password, that is not what you have the privilege to downvote for - please leave a comment instead, or edit the question adding why passwords shouldn't be stored as plain text.

Answer (score 2):

The right way is to UPDATE because in that table you will have multiple columns and you don't want to miss something.

```
UPDATE user SET name='username' WHERE id=1
```